# How can I acces another column in entity list?

Tags: java, jpa, jakarta-ee, backend, jpql

I write my backend in JavaEE with the usage of JPA.
I have a entity with a list in it.

```
public class Lesson {

    @Id
    private String id;
    private List<Time> times;
```

Time Entity:

```
@Entity
public class Time {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int id;
    private String assigned_room;
```

I want to get a List of Lessons which have a specific assigned_room.

For example:

Lesson: id=1, times{id:1, assigned_room:room123 -- id:2 assigned_room_:room321 -- id:3 assigned_room:room123}

Then I want when I want all lessons in room123 with times ... I tried:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Lesson.getWithRoomId", query = "select l from Lesson l where :id member of l.times")
```

But following error occured:

```
Parameter value [room123] did not match expected type [... .entities.Time (n/a)]
```

Has anyone an idea how to fix the error or a solution for the problem?
Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is in your `member of` clause as your supplying the id of the room but `l.times` is a collection of type `Time`. You could for example use the following query:

```
SELECT l FROM Lesson l JOIN l.times t WHERE t.assigned_room = :id
```